# Best way to split an arraylist based on a category

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList, where DataType is a class:

```
class DataType {
  String id;
  String dType;
  String description;
  // setters and getters follow
}
```

With the given `ArrayList<Datatype>`, I want to create sub lists, such that every sublist has the same value for `dType`. i.e all `DataType` Objects having same value for `dType` should come in one sublist and so on.

Further, all sublists will be added to an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Datatype>>` as created.

Could someone please suggest the most appropriate approach for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I'd do this is to create a Map:

```
Map<String, List<DataType>> data;
```

Then loop through your original array, for each value insert them into the Map using dType as the key.

```
for (DataType dt: toSort) {
    List<DataType> list = data.get(dt.dType);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        data.put(dt.dType, list);
    }
    list.add(dt);
}
```

Now you have them all sorted nicely.

Comment: It is one of the nicest solution..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would create a hash map: `HashMap<DataType, List<Data>>`. Make sure you override `equals()` and `hashCode()` for your `DataType` class.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a `HashMap<String, List<DataType>>` by manually iterating over the list. In addition to that, if you can use a 3rd party library, then consider using [Guava's `Multimaps.index`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) method:

```
Function<DataType, String> groupFunction = new Function<DataType, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(DataType dataType) {
            return dataType.getDType();
        }
};

ImmutableListMultimap<String, DataType> grouped = Multimaps.index(persons, groupFunction);

System.out.println(grouped);
```

Comment: Yes, using HashMap<String, List<DataType>> is one of the nicest solution..I need to check if I could use 3rd party library. In that case definitely this would be the best approach to follow..something I was actually looking for..could you please elaborate on how the apply method will work to group elements having same value for dType...also does any similar concept exist in apache.commons.collections?